df.to_csv in Python stops saving file after some time in a continuous for loop but the for loop is working fine?
The title. I am iterating through a very large csv file using Selenium and I want to append the results to a different csv file and I am using df.to_csv to do so. It works fine for some time but once I start to do something else and leave my Python program in the background, the csv file stops saving. The for loop keeps running though and I am assuming it is doing its job. When I go back to the python code, and just hover for a second or two, the csv file starts saving again.
I looked at the other solutions with some users suggesting .flush(), but that is when you are storing the csv file in a variable, which I am not in this case. I couldn't find a solution where I could potentially flush for the append to csv function.
while a < len(all_urls_snippet):
    last_last_height = 0
    last_height = 0
    now_height = 0

    uniques = set()
    driver.get(all_urls_snippet[a])
    time.sleep(3)
    now_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        if last_last_height == last_height == now_height:
            break
                    
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 400)")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        last_last_height = last_height
        last_height = now_height
        now_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        text = driver.find_elements("xpath", ".//div[contains(@class, 'status cursor-pointer focusable')]")

        for b in range(len(text)):
            comment_id = text[b].find_element("xpath", ".//div[contains(@class, 'status__wrapper space-y-4 status-public status-reply p-4')]")
            if comment_id.get_attribute("data-id") in uniques:
                continue
            else:
                uniques.add(comment_id.get_attribute("data-id"))
                like_button = comment_id.find_elements("xpath", ".//button[contains(@title, 'Like')]")
                for i in range(len(like_button)):
                    if like_button[i].text == "":
                        like_buttons.append(0)
                    else:
                        like_buttons.append(int(like_button[i].text))
            <<more code like this>>
    
    a = a + 1

    columnsAll = [<<columns>>]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columnsAll)
    df = df.T
    df.to_csv('comments.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)

EDIT: Could be that I was running a heavy game while the code was running in the background? I'm not sure what may be the reason. Regardless, is there any way I can force the code to save every time?

Please include a minimal working example

Yeah sorry, done
